# How to add a "share" button in individual posts in Blogger?

Tags: facebook, button, share, blogger

As captioned. I searched online but those tutorial just didn't work!

Thank you very much!

Comment: check this link : http://www.windroidclub.com/2014/03/add-facebook-like-send-share-button-to.html

Answer (score 2):

**Code for Facebook Share count button:**

`<div style="float:right;padding:4px;">
<a expr:share_url='data:post.url' name='fb_share' rel='nofollow' type='box_count'/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share"/>
</div>`

**To install on your Blogger blog:**

- Login to your Blogger Dashboard and navigate to Layout > Edit Html and check the check box which says “Expand  widget templates”.
- Find this piece of code
  `<div class='post-header-line-1'/>`
- after that place the Facebook share button code (as above)
- If you were unable to find this code in your template,then look for the first occurrence of  `<data:post.body/>`
  and immediately before that paste our Facebook Share button code(that you copied).

Save the template and you should get a facebook share count button near the heading of each of your blog posts.

Source: http://bloggermustseo.blogspot.com.au/

Comment: Thanks Andy but it is not working. I put the code under    <div class='post-footer-line post-footer-line-3'/>    and my blog turned into nothing except a # symbol on the top left corner.

Comment: Try the following code for the Facebook Share button: `<div style='float:left;padding:5px 5px 5px 0;'>
<a expr:share_url='data:post.url' href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php' name='fb_share' type='box_count'>Share</a><script src='http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share' type='text/javascript'></script>`